# How to enter network name and password to connect via ethernet in Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I should start by saying that I am very new at this.

I installed Ubuntu Server on an old laptop via a bootable USB. I have no wireless-tools, so I need to be able to connect to the internet via ethernet, so I can download further packages in order to finish setting the laptop up for what I want to do with it (mostly just C programming).

How do I connect to the internet via ethernet? If someone has a step by step guide, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 20.10

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml yields:
#This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
ethernets: {}
version: 2

Thanks so much!

Comment: step one get ethernet cable step two plug cable into router step three plug other end of cable into laptop that's it it should connect automatically and you will have internet (as long as your router/modem is on and connected)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of thee teminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: lsb_release -d`. What sort of username and password are required? TTLS? PEAP? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to find the name of your ethernet interface using a terminal command:

```
ip addr show
```

Your interface will have a name like eno1 or enp3s0 or similar. Here is an example from my machine:

```
enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether xx:f7:28:ae:83:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In this example, my ethernet interface is enp0s25. We’ll use that in the next steps.

Next, with the ethernet cable attached, try:

```
sudo dhclient -v enp0s25
```

Of course, substitute your interface name here.

If successful, the result will end with something like:

> Bound to 192.168.1.156 – Renewal in 3005 seconds

If you wish to make this permanent and automatic, or specify a static IP address by amending your netplan file, please post back and I will edit this answer to show the process.

Comment: It worked! I have successfully installed what I need to. Thanks so much!!! I really appreciate the help and time that you have taken

Comment: Glad it's working! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. The searchers will appreciate it. https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Done. Sorry I didn't accept it sooner. I didn't realize that's how askubuntu worked. Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 0):

The 'network-manager' package comes installed with *most Ubuntu flavors.* That should also include Ubuntu-Server software as without it, the primary use for the OS will invalidate. Theoretically you should just be able to plug-in the Ethernet cable and call it a day.

Assuming that's not the case:
Connect the Ethernet cable to the computer directly.

Edit */etc/network/interfaces* by using the command (on terminal):

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

In there you need to append the following lines to the **end of the file.**

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Exit and save by doing Ctrl+X and hitting Y to save.
Then run:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

Voila! You should have internet connection. It might be a bit slow and clunky, but definitely download the 'network-manager' package to make it work without editing too much. I'll leave the command below, just in case.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: Network Manager is not installed by default in Ubuntu Server. As well, `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated in 17.10 and later. Without knowing his version, we don't know if it is appropriate or not. Finally, your answer does not answer the method to supply an 802.1x username and password.

Comment: Don't worry about the username and password. That was a mistake. I have updated the question to better reflect what is going on. Thanks!